# Create custom class for Navigation Controller (Immediate crash)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, class, storyboard

I'm working on a Storyboards based app which constitutes of **multiple view controllers** linked via a **Navigation Controller** (initial view controller). This is used as the home screen. **I'm using static cells and a static table view**.

Now, I want to hook up some labels, buttons, etc as outlets/actions to "*the .h*" file and subsequently write custom methods in the .m file. But (as expected?) there's yet no custom class to select from in the **identity inspector**. So I created a new custom class as a subclass of **UITableViewController** (*which seems to be the correct one?*)

My new, custom class is now hooked up to my storyboard view controller. I then enter (what I believe to be) the correct **numberOfSectionsInTableView**: 1, and **numberOfRowsInSection**:5 (I got 1 section including 5 rows). When ran, it immediately crashes with the following error:

*Terminating app due to uncaught exception '`NSInternalInconsistencyException`', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier Cell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'*

If return 0 sections and 0 rows, everything works fine (expect there are no rows displayed). **Once I return anything > 0 in either of them, it crashes with this error.**

What have I missed? Is there anything else I'm supposed to add to the file before it can be attached as a custom class and I can use it as any other custom class? Again, I've set up everything in the interface builder (storyboard), including the table cell rows, its styling, etc. What am I doing wrong?

My Table View Setup

[image: My Table View Setup]

My Table Cell Setup

[image]

Comment: Do you have a prototype cell defined in the storyboard for your UITableView?

Comment: Do you have a `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method defined?

Comment: I think the cell id is the issue.  Make sure you have a prototype cell defined with a reuse identifier of "Cell", since that what your dequeue is looking for.

Comment: @Kekoa no I'm using static cells (if that has anything to do with it?), hence Content: Static Cells, rather than Dynamic Prototypes but that might be a different thing? `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` yes the default one: static NSString `*CellIdentifier = @"Cell"; etc...`

Comment: @danh : I'm sure you're right. How do I define a prototype cell as Cell in the interface builder storyboard (if that's where I do it) ?

Comment: If you are using static cells make sure your TableView has "Static Cells" selected for the "Content" field. Also, if you are using static cells, don't set your dataSource or delegate, and don't implement the numberOfSections/numberOfRowsInSection methods.

Comment: @Kekoa yes I have (see added images in my question). I'm not aware of any dataSource or delegate, I've not done it but perhaps XCode did it for me? What do you mean by "dont implement it". It's already there, should I just comment it out? At least, that did not work.

Comment: I would recommend reading up on the details of how data gets put into a UITableView. This is a pretty good guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH6-SW10

Comment: @Lindros - Kekoa is right, too.  See my answer below... in storyboard, find that table, make sure it has a prototype cell painted, select that cell, go to attributes inspector and set it's Identifier.

Comment: @Kekoa you're right but I'm sure there's a more minor issue in this case. Any further suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is the answer:  in storyboard, make sure a prototype cell is painted on the table view (the one in the crashing view controller) and make sure it has a reuse identifier set to "Cell".  Your code for rowAtIndexPath: is trying to dequeue a cell with that identifier and it's not there.

The identifier can be set using the attributes inspector (the middle tab on the upper right) in storyboard.

Comment: Thanks I think i see what you mean. But what do you mean by "a prototype cell is painted on the table view", painted, like highlighted/selected? I can't find anything closely resembeling the "reuse identifier" label you mention. Please have a look the print screens I added above and see if you can point out what I should change and where.

Comment: In the lower right, there are objects you can paint by dragging them in.  Find the tableViewCell and drag it into your table.  Then inspect it with the attributes inspector.

Comment: thanks again. It now has "Cell" as the identifier but same error.. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry Cell, capitalized. It doesn't seem to do it. On just one of them or all cells? I've tried both

Comment: I'm stumped.  The error is definitely about not having a cell in the table with that identifier.  Sound like you do now, if you put a breakpoint on the dequeueReusable method, you'll see it makes it to there, but then crashes when you step over that.

Comment: I agree, It seems as if that's what its looking for. I updated the images in my question so you can have a look and make sure I didn't enter it in the wrong place or something. Yep you're right it gets there but right after, it crashes big time. Any further suggestions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24248/discussion-between-danh-and-lindros)

Comment: Big thanks to @danh for finding a solution to my problem. We added Cell as the identifier to all table cell and then got rid of the table view data source methods. Also big thanks to the Swedish speaking rdelmar for all his help on this.