# Can not set my iOS's NavigationItem

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I got a NavigationController(short for nv) and a ViewController(short for vc).

nv's RootViewController is vc.

## My Goal

I just want to set the NavigationItem , I want the left bar button to be BACK button(customized).since this left button shared in all ViewControllers so I don't want to write the code in the ViewController , otherwise I have to write it many times. And I can't just subclass a ViewController, since I only need my customized left bar item in just a few ViewController.

So I try adding the generating button code in my nv , but i failed.

The result is , only the original vc got customized left bar button. other vc which is push on it all got the default one.

## My Code

Here is my NavigationController's code:

```
- (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
[self createBackButton];

- (void) createBackButton{   
UIViewController* vc = [self.viewControllers lastObject];
vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
vc.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
    [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Roll Back"
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self
                                   action:backButtonPressedSelector];
}
```

But if I put my createBackButton method in my ViewController , everything works just fine. But I also Have to write this method many times. Even the sentence like [self createBackButton]

it seems that viewWillAppear isn't a good time to call my createBackButtonMethod

## My Question

In what order does the method below be called when I am pushing and hoping view controller , and where should I add my createBackButtonMethod in order to got some of the ViewController have the same left bar button without writing unnecessary code?

1、NavigationController's didload

2、NavigationController's willappear

3、ViewController(the one being pushed) 's didload

4、ViewController's willappear

---

## Answer

The the method calling order is this:
1、vc's didload
2、nv's didload
3、nv's will appear
4、vc's will appear
and then when I continue to push vc, there are only
vc's didload and vc'didload being called repeatedly.

That's why I failed, because the nv's didload will only ***be called once*** here.

Instead of writing a common parent class, I think of the pretty solution below.

#### just do the adding things in the pushingViewController:method

So I override my pushViewController: method

```
- (void) pushViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated{
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Roll Back"
                                style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:backButtonPressedSelector];
}
```

Comment: Hey man, welcome to stackoverflow. 

Do you not think that you could have tested this first part of the question with some simple printing to console with NSLog?

Second part, why can't you use the default Back button?

Comment: @Ben Thanks I will try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to make parent view controller and extend all your view controllers from it and add the needed code in there all the view controller will have it

hope i understand your question right and this answer help you with your problem good luck

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes , It can do it. But since only a few of the ViewControllers which is embedded in the NavigationController I want to customize. So I think it may be better if I can put the common code in the NavigationController, which I failed.

Comment: @tiper okay add the only needed view controller then

Comment: @tiper check this link too it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14792772/create-custom-class-for-navigation-controller-immediate-crash

Comment: I find a better solution myself, see my question's update.

Answer (score 0):

--> Put all your code in viewcontroller's viewdidload or viewwillappear.

-->Viewdidload calls only once when you push the controller and viewwillappear will call every time in any case push, pop, present, dismiss etc.

--> First will call viewdidload and then will call view will appear.